# Access to variables stored in the class object referenced by the variable

Tags: c++, objective-c++

I have abstract class `Organizm` where I store reference to class `Swiat`. I don't know how to get access to variables of object which my `Organizm` reference to. The best explain is my code:
**Organizmy.h**

```
#pragma once
class Swiat;
class Organizm
{
public:
    Swiat& swiat;
    char symbol = '?';
    int sila = 0;
    int inicjatywa = 0;
    int x=0 , y=0;
    
    virtual void Akcja()=0;
    virtual void Kolizja()=0;
    virtual void Rysowanie()=0;
    Organizm(Swiat& swiat, char symbol, int sila, int inicjatywa, int x, int y);
};
```

**Organizmy.cpp**

```
#include "Organizm.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void Organizm::Rysowanie()
{
    cout << "Hej jestem organizmem" << endl;
}

Organizm::Organizm(Swiat& swiat, char symbol, int sila, int inicjatywa, int x, int y)
    :swiat(swiat)
{
    this->symbol = symbol;
    this->sila = sila;
    this->inicjatywa = inicjatywa;
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
}
```

`Zwierze` (sub class for `Organizmy` and base class for `Czlowiek` but I'm sure it doesn't matter in my problem, it have constructor like Czlowiek but uses Organizmy constructor)
**Czlowiek.h**

```
#pragma once
#include "Zwierze.h"

class Czlowiek : public Zwierze
{
public:
    void Rysowanie() override;
    void Powiedz();
    void Akcja() override;
    Czlowiek(Swiat& swiat);
};
```

and in `Czlowiek.cpp` I try to do something like this:

```
cout<<this->swiat.x<<endl; //this mean `Czlowiek` object
```

Im getting error: incomplete type is not allowed
EDIT: I added `swiat.h` in `czlowiek.cpp` and now it works. I made img to show my question now. Is it circular dependency?
[image]

Comment: Tip: Use [constructor lists](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor) to avoid the mess of `this->` in your code.

Comment: What is `this` in the last snippet? Put it in context.

Comment: If you have a circular reference, where X needs Y and Y needs X you need to structure your header files very carefully. In your `Organizmy.cpp` you need to be sure that the compiler has access to where `Swiat` is defined.

Comment: @TedLyngmo this is Czlowiek object

Comment: @Kawson Edit the question and show it in context - in a member function.

Comment: @tadman ye, i know, I am constantly learning in this.

Comment: `class Swiat;` means to the compiler "There's this thing called Swiat, I'll tell you more about it later" but you forgot to fulfill that obligation.

Comment: `Swiat& swiat;` - this looks cool but is likely not what you want to have in the long run.

Comment: That's what I mean about "careful". You can't have one include the other. You need to have those forward declarations and leave it at that within the header file, but within the `.cpp` code you must include both.

Comment: A tip: Instead of making a comment like "_`this` mean `Czlowiek` object_" in your code. Make that clear by including enough of the member function to make that obvious.

Comment: I think you need to provide a [mre] for this to be solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to access the member `swiat` like here

```
cout<<this->swiat.x<<endl;
```

The the object must be known, but I see only a foward declaration here:

```
class Swiat;
```

You need to include the definition for `Swiat` as well. You must do something like

```
#include "Swiat.h"
```

or wherever your `Swiat` is defined.

The forward declaration helps to avoid the circular dependency in the `.h` files, but in your `Czlowiek.cpp` file you must include that file.

Comment: so how to tell about it proper way? Becuase if I include "Swiat.h" which have #include "Czlowiek.h", which have #include "Zwierze.h", which have #include "Organizm.h" which have #include "swiat.h" etc... It will be circular. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: It should work if you include it in `Czlowiek.cpp` but the real question is why it is circular. You may have to think about your class design and what their relations are.

Comment: Ok, I got it. So I'm going now think how to avoid circular dependency, and will post my questions here if I will have

Comment: Sometimes a circular dependency is unavoidable, but somtimes it's just because one didn't think of the objects and their relations properly and it could be avoided with a better design.

Comment: Is it better to circular dependency in header or cpp file? (my intuition tells me cpp) Because I can't see option to avoid it... I'm thinking about it right now. But Swiat class have to know about Czlowiek, so I will have to include Czlowiek in Swiat.cpp. (Czlowiek includes Zwierze>>>Organizm). But I will have to add more sub classes for Zwierze, and Swiat will have to know about it so I will have to include for example "Dog.h" in Swiat.cpp. It will dependency circular. Is there another option?

Comment: @Kawson I made a suggestion that you clarify your question by making a [mre] (if this answer doesn't answer your question).

Comment: @TedLyngmo Ye I saw Im doing img to maybe better show.